# Turn off backlit keyboard when computer goes to sleep

Tags: keyboard, sleep, power-management, backlight

I just bought a backlit keyboard from a not so known brand. It doesnt have any good drivers. My issue is when I put my computer to sleep or even turn it off, all the leds underneath the keys stay on.

Is there some power management option that lets you turn this off? Thanks!

Comment: even if it is a not so know brand, it could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Unless something like that was written into the driver itself, its highly unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

If it has batteries, there is simply no way to turn it off as it is most likely that the lights are independent of anything else.

If it came with some sort of driver, look through all the options.

If it did not come with drivers and is powered through the USB or PS/2 cable, you may have some luck by disabling all options in your BIOS such as "wake on keypress" or similar.

That being said, I have dealt with a few in the past and it is usually always on and nothing you can do about it - sorry!